# How can I make a new instance of an object in Java?

Tags: java

I am making a simple email application in Java.  I have an `Account` class.  Each `Account` class has a `username` and `password` attribute.  I want to be able to create a new instance of the `Account` class from another class.  How can I do this?  It seems like it should be something very simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Account` has a *copy constructor*, it's trivial:

```
Account newAccount = new Account(otherAccount);
```

If it does not, you can probably do something like

```
String username = otherAccount.getUserName();
String password = otherAccount.getPassword();
Account newAccount = new Account(username, password);
```

Obviously I just had to make up some of these method names and things, but you get the idea.

Comment: Hm okay I get what you are saying, but I want to use a `createAccount` function to make a new account that I could then add to a list.  This way, I can login by going into the list and checking to see if the password of the account is correct.  Could I make an `Account`, say `array.add(newAccount)`, then make another `Account` and still be able to access both in the array?

Comment: Sure -- nothing I did above would be destructive to the original Account object.

Comment: Okay, so it is as simple as using the same variable over and over.  That's what I was wondering. Thank you

Comment: Hmmm. I *think* so, if I understand what you're asking. Objects are completely separate from the variables that refer to them. If you'r storing `Account` objects in a `List`, then all your `Account`s will remain available even if, at one time or another, you've used the same variable(s) outside the `List` to point to them.

Comment: Yeah, this hearkens back to my first java class where we drew squares and lines to variables.  You erase the line but the square is still there.  Gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

```
Account newAccount=new Account(username, password);
```

But surely there's more to the question than that...

```
Account copyOfAccount=new Account(oldAccount.getUsername(), 
   oldAccount.getPassword());
```

That's going to create a copy of an old account without internal state...

```
Account cloneOfAccount=oldAccount.clone();
```

That will clone Account if it's cloneable, along with whatever state the clone() replicates...

Still not sure what aspect of the process is unclear.

Comment: I want to be able to make multiple accounts and add them to a list. Will the instance of the first `Account` still be in the array even though the `newAccount` is pointing to the second `Account` I created?

Comment: sure, the old reference isn't going to go away until you change it or let the reference go out of scope entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use this code somewhere in the other class:

```
Account account = new Account();
```

However if you want that object to be called somewhere in the other class you should write something like:

```
public class Other {
   Account account;

   Other() {
       account = new Account();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Account implements Cloneable interface, you could also do

```
Account copy = oldAccount.clone();
```